# Help with this coordinate geometry question involving cirlces and parabolas.

Tags: circles, analytic-geometry

**Question:** A point $P$ in a plane moves such that it remains at a fixed distance $r$ from a fixed point $A\equiv(r,r)$.

(i) Find the equation of the locus of point $P$ (in terms of $r$).

Another point $Q$ in the same plane moves such that it is equidistant from the point $A$ and the line $y=c$, for some constant $c\neq r$.

(ii) Find the equation of the locus of point $Q$ (in terms of $r$ and $c$).

(iii) If the locus of $P$ and that of $Q$ intersect at exactly one point, find the two possible values of $c$ (in terms of $r$).

(iv) For each of the two values of $c$ found in (iii) above, deduce the coordinates of the respective point of intersection (in terms of $r$).

**Solution:** (i) Let $P\equiv(x,y)$. The distance of $P$ from $(r,r)$ is $r$, so
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{(x-r)^2+(y-r)^2}=r.
\end{align*}
This gives us:
\begin{align}
x^2+y^2-2rx-2ry+r^2=0.
\end{align}
(ii)Let $Q\equiv(x,y)$. The perpendicular distance of $Q$ from $y=c$ is equal to its distance from $(r,r)$. Then,
\begin{align*}
y-c=\sqrt{(x-r)^2+(y-r)^2}&\Rightarrow(y-c)^2=(x-r)^2+(y-r)^2\\
&\Rightarrow -2cy+c^2=x^2-2rx-2ry+2r^2.
\end{align*}
Making $y$ subject of the formula:
\begin{align*}
y=\dfrac{x^2-2rx+(2r^2-c^2)}{2(r-c)}.
\end{align*}

*In order to check my working till this point I took $r=5$ and $c=3$. This means that last equation gives the parabola $y=(x^2-10x+41)/4$ and plotting this along with the locus of $P$ gives [this](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiIzIiwiY29sb3IiOiIjMDAwMDAwIn0seyJ0eXBlIjoyLCJlcXgiOiI1KzVjb3MocykiLCJlcXkiOiI1KzVzaW4ocykiLCJjb2xvciI6IiNmZjAwMDAiLCJzbWluIjoiMCIsInNtYXgiOiIycGkiLCJzc3RlcCI6Ii4wMSJ9LHsidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiIoeF4yLTEweCs0MSkvNCIsImNvbG9yIjoiIzAwMDAwMCJ9LHsidHlwZSI6MywiZXEiOltbIjUiLCI1Il1dLCJjb2xvciI6IiMwMDAwMDAifSx7InR5cGUiOjEwMDAsIndpbmRvdyI6WyItNy4zNzAyMTQ4NDM3NDk5OTIiLCIxOC4wMjA0MTAxNTYyNDk5OSIsIi0xLjc0MTk5MjE4NzQ5OTk5ODgiLCIxMy44ODMwMDc4MTI0OTk5OTQiXX1d) which seems to make sense.

(iii) **I am stuck here:** Looking at my graph I don't know how this is even *possible*.

Comment: Obvious choices are $c=3r$ and $c=-r$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe there are always things that seem obvious to us, doesn't mean they are to others

Comment: @G-Man You're right, maby the hint: "Draw a picture with $c=-r$ and $c=3r$." would have been more appropriate.